Failing to detect clip in audio file
I am trying to find all the locations of a drum clip in a piece of audio. This drum clip is a digital sample that is repeated at intervals. I have had reasonable success at removing the clip completely from the audio.
To find its location, I take the inverse of the clip (-c) and slide it along one sample at a time, mixing it with the audio window, w, at that point. The length of c and w are the same. The result of doing this for four instances of the drum clip in the audio is as follows:

where the green line is the energy of c, the blue line is the energy of w, and the orange line is the energy of w-c. I calculate the energy as the sum of the squares.
So I detect the instances at the troughs in the orange curve where Energy(w-c) < Energy(w).
As you can see, I can detect three of the instances this way. However, I fail to detect the instance at the 142,000 mark, even though there is an instance there too.
This is the graph of the window at the first occurrence, w is orange and c is blue in the top graph. w-c appears in the bottom graph below:

The second occurrence I fail to detect, is as follows (the location of w might be wrong as I fail to detect its exact location):

The clip c can of course be distorted for each occurrence by for example compression. The rippling of the orange curve in the first graph is caused by c and -c interacting with each other as they phase in and out with each other, and also this can occur with other elements in the audio.
What do you think is the main reason why I fail to reduce the energy for the second occurrence? Can I process the audio to reduce the risk of this happening, like filtering it perhaps?
How can I make my detection algorithm more robust?
UPDATE
If I multiple the values in w by the corresponding values in c, as I slide the clip along the length of the audio, I get:

Cross correlation:
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from util import read
import numpy as np

sample_rate = 192000
audio = read("audio.aiff", sample_rate)    
clip = read("clip.aiff", sample_rate)

result = np.correlate(audio, clip)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(result)
plt.show()

Resulting graph:

Cross correlation dividing by volume:

Graph shows correlation, volume, then correlation / volume:

Code for this:
clip_ss = np.sum(np.square(clip))

volume=np.sqrt(
    np.array(
        np.fromiter(
            (
                np.sum(np.square(i))
                for i in lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(audio, len(clip))
            ),
            clip.dtype
        )*clip_ss
    )
)

corrolation = np.correlate(audio, clip)

result = np.divide(corrolation,volume)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1)
ax[0].plot(corrolation)
ax[1].plot(volume)
ax[2].plot(result)
plt.show()

If I cut the clip size down to 5000 sample, I get the following:

You can see another clip instance emerge beyond sample 350,000 in the audio, which was cut off in the earlier graph since the audio that could be correlated earlier was shorter.
If I find starting point of each of the four instances, and instead of doing summing the dot product at that point, I instead to a cumulative sum, I get the following for each instance:

Where orange is for the instance I am struggling to detect.

For the detection part, have you heard about correlation?

@Jdip I did try what I believe is correlation, where I have a sliding window, where I multiple each sample in the window with the corresponding sample in the clip and sum the result. I've added the graph for this and it appears to be suffering from the same issue.

@Baz:  I recommend using cross correlation as this is the standard method for this type of thing. It is a mathematically well defined process and it's not what you are doing. I suggest reading up on it, trying it and report back on any problems you may encounter.

@Hilmar I've added the cross correlation graph to my question and the code I'm using. The graph is very similar to my other graphs. And I'm not seeing a clear spike at round 150,000 where one of my clips is located. Without this spike it is difficult for me to establish the four occurrences of the clip in the audio.

@Baz can you calculate the cross-correlation of the signal $X$ with the clip signal $Y$, but divide it by the square root of the energy of the signal $Y$ (of length $N$) in the window? I.e., $$R_{XY}(t) = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X(t+k) Y^*(k)}{\sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X(t+k)^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}Y(k)^2\right)}}$$? That way, the volume of sound doesn't play a role in the amplitude of the correlation peak.

@Marcus Müller thanks for your suggestion. I've added the relevant graphs to my question showing the result of your equation.

it would then seem that your clip at position 142,000 is actually not there :)

@Marcus Müller If I reduce the length of the clip down to 5,000 (my SR is 192k) then you can see the 142,000 instance. Clip length was 50,000 initially. Added a graph for that too above.

since your cross-correlation formula is linear, that would imply that your long version doesn't correlate well with the short version. I'm not sure how that could happen!

@Marcus Müller The drum clip, after its attack, has a tone that is getting slower over its length, for a large part of the clip. I guess the audio has another sound with a similar tone that is out of phase with the drum clip.

@Marcus Müller I've added another graph to the end of my question. Here I am doing an accumulative sum instead of a sum and I can see that something different starts happening 5,000 samples into the second instance.
